# When a comment gets upvoted, the real time updater tells me there is a new comment

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, live-refresh

Maybe this isn't exactly a bug, but it's kinda weird when you click to see more comments and all it does increment the upvote counter on one of the comments.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't just circumstantial that a comment got up voted when a new comment was posted (and the presumably deleted)? I can't reproduce this behaviour.

Comment: It could be incidental, but it would have had less than a 3 second window when it happened to me.  I will upvote your comment in about 60 seconds from now

Comment: Hmm, no notification of the up vote on my end.

Comment: This has happened to me a few times as well. Although, I just dismiss it because it doesn't bother me that much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a case where a person can comment and then delete their comment and the "see more comments" will still be displayed.  Somebody must have upvoted your comment or another comment prior to that sequence of events which led to your experience.  The only update we notify on is for the addition of a new comment.